# not able to bind the child grid to second row in kendo Hierarchy UI grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have got parent grid and child grid and I am using [kendo UI Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html)(Hierarchy grid format)
to bind the child grid data to corresponding row in parent grid  for that I am able to show child grid for only first row and not able to show same details for another rows ...

This is my view for that grid ...

```
@model IEnumerable<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeesDetailsModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeesDetailsModel>()
        .Name("ParentGrids")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeID).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeFirstName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeSecondName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeCity).Width(100);         

        })               
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "HierarchyGridDisplay"))            
        )               
)
    <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.ShipDescriptionModel>()
            .Name("ChildGrids")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(70);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(6)
                .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "HierarchyGridDisplay"))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
    </script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
</script>
}
```

and this is my model

```
public class EmployeesDetailsModel
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSecondName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCity { get; set; }        
}
public class ShipDescriptionModel
{
    public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
    public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
    public string ShipName { get; set; }       
}
public class EmployeeShipModel
{
    public EmployeesDetailsModel employeesshipments { get; set; }
    public ShipDescriptionModel shipinfo { get; set; }   
}
```

would you pls suggest any ideas and any changes need to be done in `view` for showing child grid data to another rows as well... Many thanks

pls look at the images attached below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is because you have a static id for the grid. You should try and give it a dynamic one, so different child grids can be created. This is why it only works on the first record, because you have no variation for the name of the grid. 
Try to do this instead:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.ShipDescriptionModel>()
        .Name("ChildGrid_#=EmployeeID#")
```

What is happening is that the EmployeeId from the parent grid is being pulled down, and being used for the naming convention of the grid. This way you can have as many child grids as like you like.